# Primary key with auto increment

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

I have an issue with the auto increment, same times the numbers changed and not keep the increment as I defined. 
Attached the code and image of the table.

```
    // Table 3 creation (Coupon)
    try {
    java.sql.Statement stmt3 = conn.createStatement();
    sql = "create table Coupon("
            + "ID bigint not null primary key generated always as identity(start with 1, increment by 1), "
            + "TITLE varchar(30) not null, " 
            + "START_DATE DATE not null, " 
            + "END_DATE DATE not null,"
            + "AMOUNT INTEGER not null," 
            + "TYPE varchar(10) not null," 
            + "MESSAGE varchar(30) not null,"
            + "PRICE double not null,"
            + "IMAGE varchar(200) not null)";
    stmt3.executeUpdate(sql);
    System.out.println("success:" + sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like either somebody inserted and then deleted 99 rows or somebody modified the current AUTO_INCREMENT value in the database itself. Theres no reason for the database to skip 99 values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't tag the question with a database.  However, no database guarantees that an auto-increment/serial/identity column will always increment by just "1".

There is a lot of overhead to such a guarantee.

Instead, the guarantee is that when the column is unique, the next value will be larger than the previous value and the difference will be a multiple of the increment.

Some reasons why gapless increments require lots of work:

- deletion of records removes values.
- rolled back transactions may "use up" values.
- parallel databases may cache values on different nodes.

There are ways around this, but they are expensive and usually unnecessary.